# Dojo _hasDropDown - How do I declaratively bind the properties?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dojo, dijit.form

ExpandableSearchComponent.html:

```
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/_HasDropDown" data-dojo-props="dropDown: 'containerNode'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
        name="${SearchViewFieldName}Textbox"
        class="${baseClass}Textbox"
        data-dojo-props="placeholder:'${fieldName}'"></div>
        <div class="${baseClass}Container" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ExpandableSearchComponent.js:

```
/**
 * Javascript for ExpandableSearchComponent
 */
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/ExpandableSearchComponent.html",
        "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/_HasDropDown" ], function(declare,
        _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template, TextBox) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin ], {
        templateString : template,
        SearchViewFieldName : "",
        fieldName : ""
    });

});
```

Intended to be used like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="js/widgets/ExpandableSearchComponent"                                  
    data-dojo-props="SearchViewFieldName: 'machineSearchView.name', fieldName: 'Name:'">    
    <div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory"                                                 
        data-dojo-id="machineNameStore"                                                     
        data-dojo-props="<s:property value='%{getNameJsonString()}'/>"></div>               
    <s:set name="MachineName" value="machineSearchView.name"                                
        scope="request"></s:set>                                                            
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"                                               
        data-dojo-props="store:machineNameStore, searchAttr:'name', value:'${MachineName}'" 
        name="machineSearchView.name" id="machineSearchView.name"></div>                    
</div>
```

The intent is:

1. The user at first only sees the textbox with the placeholder.
2. When they click it, the containerNode expands and shows what's inside the containerNode, which can either be a `dijit/Select`, a `dijit/form/ComboBox` or a `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`. The internal element is also automatically expanded.
3. The user selects a value in the internal select, which then gets modified a bit so it's shown in the TextBox as `${fieldName}:${value}`.

The data that's eventually processed by the server is the value of the internal element.

The problem I'm currently facing is that I have no idea how to make the _HasDropDown work properly as mentioned above. It renders the TextBox as an element with height 0 and then immediately shows the internal element. I'm not sure how to bind the internal nodes for it to work like a dropdown should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dijit/_HasDropDown` is a mixin to add dropdown functionality to a widget by inheritance. It is not intended to be used as a widget, especially in declarative markups.

> dijit/_HasDropDown is a dijit widget mixin that provides drop-down
>   menu functionality. Widgets like dijit/form/Select,
>   dijit/form/ComboBox, dijit/form/DropDownButton, and
>   dijit/form/DateTextBox all use dijit/_HasDropDown to implement their
>   drop-down functionality.

Please refer this document on how to use `dijit/_HasDropDown`. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_HasDropDown.html

```js
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/_HasDropDown" ],
    function(declare, Button, _HasDropDown){
    return declare([Button, _HasDropDown], {
        isLoaded: function(){
            // Returns whether or not we are loaded - if our dropdown has an href,
            // then we want to check that.
            var dropDown = this.dropDown;
            return (!!dropDown && (!dropDown.href || dropDown.isLoaded));
        },

        loadDropDown: function(callback){
            // Loads our dropdown
            var dropDown = this.dropDown;
            if(!dropDown){ return; }
            if(!this.isLoaded()){
                var handler = dropDown.on("load", this, function(){
                    handler.remove();
                    callback();
                });
                dropDown.refresh();
            }else{
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide en example so it is here as reference in case the link get broken?

Comment: So I cannot do this declaratively, I have to define the properties programmatically?